# Magento : Template block has not been whitelisted error

Tags: error, blocks, cache

I have a site with a CMS page using the 'core/template' block, and getting an error `Security problem: core/template has not been whitelisted` - even though the 'core/template' is clearly listed in the System > Permissions > Blocks list as 'Allowed' - I have cleared cache multiple times, turned the block permission on and off, and still no luck.

Anyone know about this solution?